# Handling CSV files with Python in AndroidStudio causes the error FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, android, csv

So I want to make an app that works with machine learning. For machine learning I used Python, because developing for maschine learning is easier in Python. I used Sypder for that. I embedded my Python script in AndroidStudio with Chaquopy. I now have the following problem. The following line in Python gives me the following error in android studio

```
csv_path=("C:\\Test\\tellmewhen\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\klein.csv") 
dataset = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Error in AndroidStudio

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Test\\app\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\klein.csv' does not exist: b'C:\\Test\\app\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\klein.csv'
        at <python>.pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source(parsers.pyx:689)
        at <python>.pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__(parsers.pyx:382)
        at <python>.pandas.io.parsers.__init__(parsers.py:1917)
        at <python>.pandas.io.parsers._make_engine(parsers.py:1135)
        at <python>.pandas.io.parsers.__init__(parsers.py:895)
        at <python>.pandas.io.parsers._read(parsers.py:457)
        at <python>.pandas.io.parsers.parser_f(parsers.py:685)
        at <python>.mlr.<module>(mlr.py:70)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._call_with_frames_removed(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap_external.exec_module(<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:783)
        at <python>.java.android.importer.exec_module(importer.py:549)
        at <python>.java.android.importer.exec_module(importer.py:594)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:671)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:975)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
        at <python>.importlib.import_module(__init__.py:127)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_Python_getModule(chaquopy_java.pyx:156)
        at com.chaquo.python.Python.getModule(Native Method)
        at de.uni.bremen.tellmewhen.PythonKlasse.pyBerechnung(PythonKlasse.java:32)
        at de.uni.bremen.tellmewhen.AlarmDrunk.<init>(AlarmDrunk.kt:37)
        at de.uni.bremen.tellmewhen.MainActivity$Companion.addAlarmDrunk(MainActivity.kt:184)
        at de.uni.bremen.tellmewhen.FragmentNewEntryStepFour$onCreateView$5.onClick(FragmentNewEntryStepFour.kt:347)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14230)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I think the problem may be because the phone has no access to myhard drive, so it can't read the filepath. So how do you make sure that both Python and Android Studio can access a CSV file at the same time without getting an error?

Comment: I got some things wrong, please check https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/353 if you have the same problem and don't want to waste several hours with a stupid thought process